# How do I assign row names to numeric matrix so they can be displayed on a heatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap, r-rownames, complexheatmap

So I'm trying to create a Heatmap using [ComplexHeatmap package](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/) and my data has first column as a species name, e.g. "Shigella" and the next 8 columns titled by their sample id represent how many times each species were observed(as a numeric value) in a sample.

To create a Heatmap I need a numeric matrix, so I get it like this
`my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data[,c(2:9)])`, getting all columns except the first one that contains character values, then I store species name as separate data frame by
`species_name <- as.data.frame(my_data$species_name)` and then what I'm trying to do is assign species name back to their corresponding rows to display in a heatmap by using `rownames` function, but apparently this doesn't work. Simple example looks something like this:

```
Heatmap(my_matrix, rownames(species_name), show_row_names = TRUE)
```

I get no warnings nor errors, heatmap appears in a plot sections but still doesn't have row names assigned like in the image bellow, and finally my question is how do I assign them proper?

I want my Species name to be displayed as row name, e.g. ["Shigella" instead of "row 1", "Salmonella" instead of "row 2", etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVF4Q.jpg)

Comment: Try using `Heatmap(my_matrix, row_labels=rownames(species_name)) `

Answer (score 2):

You can try -

```
my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data[,c(2:9)])
rownames(my_matrix) <- my_data$species_name
Heatmap(my_matrix, show_row_names = TRUE)
```